# Java - Want to parse through eof. Code only parses once

Tags: java, parsing, eof, datainputstream

My code below only parses through the data file once.  I'm trying to get it to parse through the whole file.  Every time it finds a marker, parse the data and append it to the output file.  Currently it successfully parses the data once and then stops.  Can't figure out how to keep it looping until eof.  The data is 4 byte aligned and is in a input binary file.

```
 private static void startParse(File inFile) throws IOException {
      boolean markerFound = false;
      for (int offset = 0; !markerFound && offset < 4; offset++){
         DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile));
         for (int i = 0; i < offset; i++){
             dis.read();
         }
         try {
             int integer;
             long l;
             while((l = (integer = dis.readInt())) != MARKER) {
                 //Don't do anything
             }
             markerFound = true;
             for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
                 dis.read();
             }

     // ********************** data **********************          
             byte[] data = new byte[1016];
             for(int i = 0; i < 1016; i++){
             data[i] = (byte) dis.read();
             }

             for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                 dis.read();
             }

     // ***************** output data ********************
             if (checksumCheck(checksum) && fecfCheck(fecf)){
                 FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("ParsedData", true);
            try{
                output.write(data);
            } 
            finally{
                output.close();
            }
        }

    }               
    catch (EOFException eof) {
    }
    dis.close();
 }
 }
```

Comment: You mean it does not parse until the end of the data?

Comment: BTW, I suggest you use [FileChannel.map()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map(java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long)) for this kind of job

Comment: Yes, there is a section of data inside the file, and it only parses the first marker section of data and there is about 50 in the file.  And I said 'data' as the rest is just garbage I don't care about and am parsing out the actual 'data' I want.

Comment: Are you sure the marker is present, 4-byte aligned and of correct byte order (little/big endian)? `markerFound = integer == MARKER;`

Comment: Please include a description of the file format. Your question doesn't make much sense without it.

Comment: Big endian, 4 byte aligned, binary file.

Comment: I saw that your journey started [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840945/when-reading-a-binary-file-with-java-how) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902402/java-search-for-a-long-in-a-binary-file-input-8-byte-aligned-big-endian). So, try to give us more detail about your file, otherwise you will not get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: You should consider using a [`GatheringByteChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/GatheringByteChannel.html)

Answer (score 6):

```
markerFound = true;
```

This line is not inside a conditional and will be executed in any occurrence of the loop.
Which will of course shut down your loop because:

```
for (int offset = 0; !markerFound && offset < 4; offset++)
```

Comment: But it can only exit the while loop above it if it has found the marker.  Otherwise it will get an eof exception.  If this is not the case then I may need a further explanation as I would then be confused.

Answer (score 1):

**First thing**

You are opening the file inside your `for`, so, the reading always will start at the beginning of the file. Open it before the first `for`.

**Second**

Because of the test `!markerFound && offset < 4`, your loop will occur max 4 times.

**Third**

This code not make sense to me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < offset; i++){
    dis.read();
}
```

Because the `offset`, in the first iteration, is 0, in the next will be 1, and so on. And that loop is not necessary, you are using another loop to read bytes until reach the MARKER.

**Fourth**

If your file has "records" with fixed lenghts and the markers occurs on predictable positionings, use the DataInputStream [`skipBytes` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#skipBytes%28int%29) to go forward to next marker.

Answer (score 0):

As I'd posted in an earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16945563/1237040) to your question [Java, need a while loop to reach eof. i.e.while !eof, keep parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16945335/1237040) I'd like to state again that `DataInputStream.read()` (unlike other readXxX() methods) ***does not throw*** `EOFExcepion`.

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#read()): *(`DataInputStream` inherits `read()` from `FilterInputStream`)*

> If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value **-1** is returned.

So, to correctly check for `EOF`, usually `read(byte[])` is used in a `while` loop as follows:

```
int read = 0;
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
while ((read = dis.read(b)) != -1) { // returns numOfBytesRead or -1 at EOF
  // fos = FileOutputStream
  fos.write(b, 0, read); // (byte[], offset, numOfBytesToWrite)
}
```

#### Answer

Now, getting *back to your current question*; since, you haven't shared your binary file format it's difficult to suggest a better way to parse it. So, from the limited understanding of the way your nested loops are parsing your file currently; you need another `while` loop (as reasoned above) to *read/parse and copy* your "data" till you reach `EOF` once you've found the *marker*.

```
markerFound = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){ // move this loop inside while IF
    dis.read(); // these 11 bytes need to be skipped every time
}

// Open the file just ONCE (outside the loop)
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("ParsedData", true);

// ********************** data **********************
int read = 0;
byte[] data = new byte[1016]; // set byte buffer size

while ((read = dis.read(data)) != -1) { // read and check for EOF

    // ***************** output data ********************
    if (checksumCheck(checksum) && fecfCheck(fecf)) { // if checksum is valid
        output.write(data, 0, read); // write the number of bytes read before
    }

    // SKIP four bytes
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // or, dis.skipBytes(4); instead of the loop
        dis.read();
    }
 }

// Close the file AFTER input stream reaches EOF
output.close(); // i.e. all the data has been written
```